# Dropdown-menu Bootstrap PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to send the data from a PHP page with AJAX , but I am not able to understand how this works, I will explain what I have done so far.

**Bootstrap dropdown**:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        BOTÂO <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>                   
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="status">
        <li data="1"><a href="#">valor 1</a></li>
        <li data="2"><a href="#">valor 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**AJAX**:

```
$(document).on('click','#status li',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url  : 'exemple.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
               'valor' : $('#data').val()
        },
    });
});
```

I changed the AJAX to:

```
$(document).on('click','#status li',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url  : 'exemple.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            'valor': $(this).attr('data')
        },
    });
});
```

But does not work aswell. Any idea please?

Comment: `<li data-something="1">` and then in Ajax : `valor: $(this).data('something');`  More info - http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @phillip100 not work again! I need to fix this error....

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is...

Answer (score 0):

[`data` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) is supposed to be in format like : `data-something="foo"`.
It's then easy accessible using jQuery's [**`.attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (or [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)) method

**HTML**:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    BOTÂO <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>                   
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="status">
        <li data-something="1"><a href="#">valor 1</a></li>
        <li data-something="2"><a href="#">valor 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Script**:

In order to get server response inside your [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, you should add `success` (when things went ok) and `error` (when things went wrong) callbacks:

```
$(document).on('click','#status li',function(){
    var dd_val = $(this).attr('data-something');
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'exemple.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : { valor : dd_val},
        success : function(data){
            // do anything with server response when success:
            console.log(data);
        },
        error   : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            // do anything when error
            console.log(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/extyewg9/)**

Comment: this is working fine now, but i need to select this value from the dropdown-menu and after that input some text in a input textarea before send the AJAX request, so i make another ajax call with the arguments and work fine too, the problem is that the PHP page pick one or another AJAX request, i need synchronize the 2 AJAX call´s. It is possible?

Comment: @superuser Yes. Just make sure that one request is done (you got server response), then process your stuff and call the next Ajax. I can't help you more as I don't see details - you could make jsfiddle.

Comment: @superuser , you want to call just single ajax request with both (doropdown and textarea) values?

Comment: Yes, 1 single ajax request with the dropdown and textarea. When i click the buton send to PHP, Both VALUES are sent to the PHP page to solve a mathematical equation , then the reply is sent back to another textarea. Update the code: http://jsfiddle.net/_Luis_/qxckcwmo/4/